# AWS IAM roles Trust Relationships

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create fully automated creating of new roles in AWS and connecting this with Snowflake. To connect Snowflake with AWS we must edit trust relationships and paste their `STORAGE_AWS_EXTERNAL_ID`.

Is there any way to do this fully automated?

Comment: Sorry, but it is difficult to understand your question. Please Edit your Question to provide more information. For example, can you point us to any relevant Snowflake documentation that mentions the Trust Relationships? How would you do it manually (rather than automatically)? What would trigger the creation of such roles?

Comment: So in Snowlake part we are doing this step https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html#step-4-retrieve-the-aws-iam-user-for-your-snowflake-account. Then we must go to IAM Roles -> Trust relatioships and edit this relationship. Like in this step https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html#step-5-grant-the-iam-user-permissions-to-access-bucket-objects. I want this two steps to be fully automated

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a batch script using **AWS CLI** et **SNOW SQL** following the steps provided in the [Snowflake user guide](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html#option-1-configuring-a-snowflake-storage-integration-to-access-amazon-s3).

1. Create your AWS IAM policy and get your **policy's arn**
2. Create an AWS IAM role linked to this policy and get the **role's arn**
3. Create the snowflake storage integration linked to this role and get **STORAGE_AWS_IAM_USER_ARN** and **STORAGE_AWS_EXTERNAL_ID** from `DESC INTEGRATION` command.
4. Update the AWS IAM policy with previous values (i.e snowflake's user arn and external id).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can You tell me how to run aws commands in snowsql?

Comment: You will not be able tu run aws commands in snowsql but you can call both CLI (AWS / Snowflake) in a generic script command (windows / linux)  with variables.

Comment: But the requiment is that to not running scripts on powershell etc. I can only use a python code that I can put to aws lambda and run from there. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use **AWS sdk for python** (https://aws.amazon.com/fr/sdk-for-python/) and **Snowflake connector for python** (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector.html) in your AWS Lambda function.